# getting data from html files and saving it to models django

Tags: django

I have created multiple input fields and when i click submit i need that data to be saved into my database through models.py that i created. However I am unable to understand how to redirect that data from html to django.

This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Cars</title>
    <h1> Enter sales data to store</h1>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="billingnumber">Billing Number:</label>
        <input type="number" id="billingnumber" name="billingnumber"><br/>
        <label for="customername" >Customer Name :</label>
        <input type="text" id="customername" name="customername"><br/>
        <label for="purchasedate">Purchase Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="purchasedate" name="purchasedate"><br/>
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
        <input type="number" id="price" name="price" ><br/>
        <label for="carcompany">Car Company:</label>
        <input type="text" id="carcompany" name="carcompany"><br/>
        <label for="carmodel">Car Model:</label>
        <input type="text" id="carmodel" name="carmodel"><br/>
        <label>Car Serial Number:</label>
        <input type="number" id="carserial" name="carserial"><br/>
        <label for="mfgdate">Car Manufacturing Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="mfgdate" name="mfgdate"><br/>
        <label for="shippingdate">Shipping Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="shippingdate" name="shippingdate"><br/>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
<a href="/">Home<a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my models.py

```
class cars(models.Model):
    billingnumber = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    purchasedata = models.DateTimeField()
    carcompany = models.TextField()
    carmodel = models.TextField()
    carserialnumber = models.BigIntegerField()
    carmfgdate = models.DateTimeField()
    shippingdate = models.DateTimeField()
```

These are my url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="home"),
    url(r"^store/$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="store.html"), name="store"),
    url(r"^access/$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="access.html"), name="access"),
    url(r"^about/$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name="about"),
    ]
```

I am unable to understand how to write views.py however this is how i tried to get data

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.
from .forms import myform
from .models import cars

def get_data(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = myform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cars.billingnumber(form)
                cars.save()
                return HttpResponse('<html><body>Data Saved</body></html>')
        else:
            form = myform()
            return render(request, 'sample.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class myform(forms.Form):
    billingnumber = forms.CharField(label="billing number")
```

How can i change these files, I am a novice considering django

Comment: What does the definition of `myform` look like? And why aren't you using it in the template?

Comment: Hi, I have added my myforms script, I have no idea how to include this in a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django there is a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) which automatically creates forms from models.

## models.py

Here is the `models.py` file with small changes:

- class names should be in [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase)
- you probably don't need `TextFields`, I guess `CharField` will suffice
- if we are inside `Car` model you do not have to prepend each name with `car` (eg. it is better to write `model` instead of `carmodel`)
- use underscores for separating multi-word variables (eg. `shipping_date` instead of `shippingdate`)

So there is a file:

```
from django.db import models


class Car(models.Model):
    billing_number = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    mfg_date = models.DateTimeField()
    shipping_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

## forms.py

Now, having `Car` model ready, we can create `ModelForm`. It is as easy as that:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Car

class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = ()  # this says to include all fields from model to the form
```

If you wanted to display limited number of fields in your form you could write:

```
class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('customer', 'price', 'model')  # this would only display 3 fields on the form
```

## views.py

We have everything we need to create the view to handle model creation form.

Add a new function in `views.py` file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CarForm


def add_car(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # data sent by user
        form = CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # this will save Car info to database
            return HttpResponse('Car added to database')
    else:  # display empty form
        form = CarForm()

    return render(request, 'add_car.html', {'car_form': form})
```

## urls.py

Add this new view to `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    # your other urls
    # ...
    path('add-car', views.add_car, name='add_car'),
]
```

## templates/add_car.html

Template that `add_car` view uses:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_car' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ car_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save new car">
</form>
```

Important line is `<form action="{% url 'add_car' %}" method="post">`. This says to send POST request to `add_car` url. Url name was defined here: `path('add-car', views.add_car, name='add_car')` (`name` argument).

After applying these changes, you should be able to visit `/add-car` and fill in a form which will add a new record to the database.

## Displaying stored records

To display records that you have in your database you have to:

- add new url
- create new view to fetch records
- create new template to list cars

`urls.py` - add this line to `urlpatterns`

```
path('cars', views.car_list, name='car_list'),
```

View:

```
def car_list(request):
    return render(request, 'car_list.html', {
        # this will fetch all cars from database
        'cars': Car.objects.all()
    })
```

Now create [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language) `car_list.html` where you can display all cars

```
<ul>
    {% for car in cars %}
        <li>{{ car.model }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

## Display single record details

`urls.py` add new line:

```
path('car/<int:car_billing_number>', views.car_details, name='car_details'),
```

`views.py` Retrieving single model info is also simple

```
def car_details(request, car_billing_number):
    return render(request, 'car_details.html', {
        'car': Car.objects.get(billing_number=car_billing_number)
    })
```

And finally - the `car_details.html` template.

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
    <tr><td>Billing number</td><td>{{ car.billing_number }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Model</td><td>{{ car.model }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Company</td><td>{{ car.company }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Price</td><td>{{ car.price }} $</td></tr>
    {# and so on #}
</table>
```

Now when you have a Car with billing number `123` you can visit site `car/123` and see detailed information.

Comment: Yes this is working now, the data has been saved to database. Will it be possible for you to explain how to fetch data from database

Comment: I edited my first post and added one example of fetching data. Also, reading part 3 of Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/ might clear some things for you

Comment: I am getting car has no attribute objects.

Traceback:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cars/
Exception Value: type object 'Car' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: also i only want to fetch the data of a single car values(price, etc) depending on a user input of billing number

Comment: Regarding 'objects' attribute: you probably forgot to import Car model in views.py. Add this code on the top of the file: from .models import Car

Comment: so what if i give billing number as input and i get all of its values in html ? how can i write my views to perform this

Comment: I updated the answer once again. You should really take a look at official Django guide if you struggle, it is really well explained.

Comment: i use django<2 so i cannot import path and also i am a novice and have an assignment to submit by end of tommorow and at this rate i wont be able to complete it. I am getting an error when using url that car_details() takes 2 arguments and only one is given

Comment: I have gone through few more links and references,  I was able to finally get the data. I appreciate your time and help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use ModelForm instead of form and bound it to your cars model. This way all the model fields will be available through the form.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import cars

class myform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = cars
```

Than in your html just show all the form fields. You can do it with form.as_p or you can render each field separately inside desired html element. Check [Django form rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) for more info on form rendering.

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```